# Provide hex value as an input to gets in C

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, gets

I'm working on a simple arc injection exploit, wherein this particular string gives me the desired address of the place where I'd like to jump: `Á^F@^@`. This is the address `0x004006c1` (I'm using a 64 bit Intel processor, so x86-64 with little endian arrangement).

When I provide this string `Á^F@^@` as input to a vulnerable `gets()` routine in my function and inspect the addresses using `gdb`, the address gets modified to `0x00400681` instead of `0x004006c1`. I'm not quite sure as to why this is happening. Furthermore, is there any way to easily provide hexadecimal values to a `gets` routine at `stdin`? I've tried doing something like: `121351...12312\xc1\x06\x40\x00`, but instead of picking up `\xc1` as it is, it translates individual character to hex, so I get something like `5c78..` (hex for \ and x, followed by hex for c and 1).

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a character encoding issue: Á is U+00C1 -- a Unicode value.  However, your locale settings seem to suggest that it gets translated to UTF-8 as `\xC3\x81`, except for some reason the `\xC3` byte is dropped or swapped(?), or to GB 18030 as `\x81\x30\x86\x39`, in which case you'd see more if you printed more.  It was just a quick Python encoding test, but UTF-8 and GB 18030 are the only ones that even have a byte sequence containing `\x81`.  Personally, I'd go with the suggestion to just redirect `stdin` from a file to prevent encoding issues with character input like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just put the raw bytes into a file somewhere and pipe it directly into your application.

```
$ path/to/my_app <raw_binary_data
```

Alternatively, you could wrap the application in a shell script that converts escaped hex bytes into their corresponding byte values. The `echo` utility will do this when the `-e` switch is set on the command line, for example:

```
$ echo '\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'
\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f
$ echo -e '\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'
Hello
```

You can use this feature to process your application's input as follows:

```
while read -r line; do echo -e $line; done | path/to/my_app
```

To terminate the input, try pressing <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that really doesn't solve my problem :-/ 

`Á` still translates to `0x81` for some reason.

Comment: @user2841250 Why not just enter `\xc1` if that's what you want?